# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object however my function work

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am getting this error on Line 71 of my code, however the function of this line is executed correctly and it does what I expect it to do.

However, I noticed that my error log is full of these lines:

> [09-Dec-2013 14:54:02 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/sportve/public_html/open_event_common.php on line 71

What I have checked for:

`simple_html_dom_parser` is already included and this function that Line 71 intend to do is working.

Here is Line 71 of my code:

```
$content->find('a.openevent', 0)->innertext = '';
```

so its confusing as to what is causing this error to appear in my error log file?

Edit: here is the full code:

```
<?php       
    $url = "static/" . $cat_map[$cat]['url'];
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $content = $html->find('div#event-pane > div#e' . $event_id, 0);
    $content->find('a.openevent', 0)->innertext = '';
    $content->find('h3.lshtitle', 0)->onclick = '';
    $content->find('h3.lshtitle', 0)->tag = 'div';
    $content->find('div.lshtitle', 0)->class = 'ttl';                
?>
```

Comment: `$content` is not an object. You need to show the rest of the relevant code

Comment: Show where and how `$content` is set. If that contains variables, show what is in those variables at that time (`var_dump(..)`)

Comment: @Marc B check it again i have updated the question

Comment: @Sumurai8 check it again i have updated the question

Comment: After you create the `$content` variable, you need to make sure your call to `$html->find()` actually returned what you expected it to.  If it didn't find any elements, then it stands to reason any of the subsequent `$content->find()` calls won't work.

Comment: if find() fails, it will NOT return an object. it'll return a boolean false. You're simply assuming that the first find works. Since $content is not an object, the find obviously failed.

Comment: Look at the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm) and [the manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm). `->find( str, int )` returns `NULL` if the element doesn't exist. Calling something on `NULL` will give an error (obviously).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the information you’re providing the best and most practical solution is to simply do a check to see if `$html` and `$content` is empty or not.

9 times out of 10 when you get a **“Call to a member function [whatever the function is] on a non-object”** that basically means the object just doesn’t exist. Meaning the variable is empty. Here is your code reworked:

```
$url = "static/" . $cat_map[$cat]['url'];
if (!empty($url)) {
  $html = file_get_html($url);
  if (!empty($html)) {
    $content = $html->find('div#event-pane > div#e' . $event_id, 0);
    if (!empty($content)) {
      $content->find('a.openevent', 0)->innertext = '';
      $content->find('h3.lshtitle', 0)->onclick = '';
      $content->find('h3.lshtitle', 0)->tag = 'div';
      $content->find('div.lshtitle', 0)->class = 'ttl';
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I added a check to see if the `$url` is empty as well.

Comment: `if (!empty($html)) {` didn't work for me, but `if ($html->find('html') || $html->find('body')) {` did.