# Call to a member function find() on a non-object php on web server

Tags: php, web-services, find

i'm trying to parse a html page but i have an error, when i run a code on my localhost server (Apache) the code works, but now I uploaded the php file on a web server(Altervista) i receive this error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object.

```
if(isset($_POST['url'])){
$url =$_POST['url'];
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('div.item') as $index) {
    echo $index->find('div.item_head/div.org/h2.rgs/a',0)->plaintext;
}
```

}

Comment: your html is not loaded properly. verify that $url is not empty and it's a valid url, then verify that html content is properly loaded

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473748/php-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object-however-my-fun

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I solved simply by changing hosting service!